# How to improve the efficiency and speed of my Ruby code

Tags: ruby, performance

I'm currently searching files for certain words or regexes using the String.scan method. However, when running the script on 1.9GB of data, it takes about 3 hours. I think this may be due to the repeated use of .scan. 
The code looks a lot like below, is there a way to improve the speed even if it means without scan?

1. String 'text' is the text from a file (50k words) for this example.
2. The 'item.getCustomeMetadata.putText() places the results in a separate program.
3. The Code repeats itself as one array works for `pdCount` and the other for `idrCount`

`idNames = [/UK[0-9]{3,6}/ , /\s*[A-C,E,G-H,J-PR-T,W-Z]{2}(?:\s*\d\s*){6}[a-dfmA-DFM]?\s*/]
    idCats = ["IG_EmpID" ,"IG_SSN" ]`

```
idNames.each_with_index do |val, index|
    textScan = text.scan(val).size
    if textScan > idrHighest
        idrHighest = textScan
    end
    volume = volume + textScan
    item.getCustomMetadata.putText(idCats[index], textScan)
    if textScan != 0
        idrCount +=1
    end
end

pdRegNames = [/(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}/ , /020[0-9]{7}/ , /[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-+]+@(infogov|gmail|hotmail|yahoo|outlook|aol|msn|verizon)(\.[a-z]{2,3}){1,2}/ , /(0[1-9]|[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-\/ .](0[1-9]|[1-9]|1[012])[-\/ .](19|20)\d\d/ , /\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/, /[A-Z0-9]{5}\d[0156]\d([0][1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\d[A-Z0-9]{3}[A-Z]{2}/,/([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y0-9][A-HJKS-UW0-9]?[A-HJKS-UW0-9]?)\s*([0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2})/i]
pdRegCats = ["IG_Phone","IG_Phone2","IG_Email","IG_DOB" , "IG_FIP", "IG_License", "IG_Address"]

pdRegNames.each_with_index do |val, index|
    textScan = text.scan(val).size
    if textScan > pdHighest
        pdHighest = textScan
    end
    volume = volume + textScan
    item.getCustomMetadata.putText(pdRegCats[index], textScan)
    if textScan != 0
        pdCount +=1
    end
end

maritalNames = ["Married" , "Divorced" , "Civil Partnership"]

temp = volume
maritalNames.each do |val|
    textScan = text.scan(/#{val}/i).size
    if textScan > pdHighest
        pdHighest = textScan
    end
    volume = volume + textScan
    item.getCustomMetadata.putText("IG_Marital", (volume - temp).round(0))
    if textScan != 0
        pdCount +=1
    end
end

foundSort = text.scan(/[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/)
textScan = 0
foundSort.each do |sort|
    if sortArray.include? sort
        textScan +=1
    end
end
if textScan > pdHighest
    pdHighest = textScan
end
volume = volume + textScan
item.getCustomMetadata.putText("IG_Sort", textScan)
if textScan != 0
    pdCount +=1
end
```

`

This runs once per file. So you can image this going over millions. I was thinking of using threads, creating one per file, but this did not work for me.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ruby is a lovely language; but for speedy text processing, use bash. Look into `grep` and `awk`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it needs to work with a program which only accepts Ruby, otherwise I would definitely go with bash. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a couple of observations.

1. Most importantly - You are scanning the entire file each time you call scan() - and you are doing this within loops.  This is a bad idea.
2. Your regexes are pretty complicated, and regex itself is not fast.

Are your data files structured?  Is the data delimited with tabs, pipes or commas?  Does data typically appear in the same place on subsequent lines?

Can you split the file into smaller working sets of at most a megabyte in size?  This will make searching the strings in memory significantly faster.

Honestly, if I was faced with this, I'd look for delimeters or some sort of record structure - if the data is at all regular it is possible to make assumptions and optimizations based on these and then deal with errors as they occur.  If the data is totally free-form then the only option is to split the file into smaller units and use multiple threads to process them.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I can do little of what you suggested. The whole situation is difficult to work around. I'm running the script to work with another program so currently I'm attempting to use more of the program's functions to run faster.